# Dataset for simultaneous object detection, 6D pose estimation and grasp detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

I am trying to find a dataset which meets any of the following requirements.

1. Dataset of RGB or RGBD images with object bbox annotations, 6d pose annotations and grasp annotations.
2. Dataset of RGB or RGBD images with object bbox annotations and grasp annotations.

I have worked with Cornell grasp dataset and linemod 6d object pose estimation dataset separately.
I am trying to build a unified model that does all these tasks together and trying to find available dataset for the same.